# Can an Arcane Trickster use Mage Hand Legerdemain to attempt to steal an unheld weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue

It's pretty obvious a straight-up disarm would not work, as this requires an attack roll and the mage hand can't attack, but can they grab a bow, hand crossbow, etc. while the opponent is wielding something else? This is basically retrieving an object so perhaps contested by their Perception roll to check if they notice and stop it from happening?

This has some obvious synergy with, for example, the *booming blade* spell and Mobile feat, where if they want to be able to attack they have to move and trigger extra damage or pull out a ranged weapon.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take our [tour] if you have a chance. It appears that your question may already have an answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102358/can-mage-hand-grab-opponents-items). If there is something about your specific example that isn't addressed in that question, please [edit] your question to make that more clear.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that similar question; While I didn't see it before I asked - the scope is broader and didn't directly address the question as it was referring to different specific actions.

Comment: The other question is about Mage Hand. This question is specifically about Mage Hand Legerdemain. Yeah, they are related, but the other question's feature and scenario are only related to this question because some of the other question's answers happen to offer additional commentary that intersects with this question's core feature and scenario. This is why I am voting to reopen (and why I answered despite close votes, because I do not believe this to be a duplicate).

Comment: @user44459 So you're asking if "You can retrieve an object in a container worn or carried by another creature." counts for weapons they are not wielding. It seems like you're asking more about "does not equipping a weapon mean it is stowed and valid for Legerdemain." I think that's different enough to warrant a reopen vote.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, if the weapon is stored in a container.

If the weapon is not being wielded by the opponent and is in a container they are wearing or carrying (such as a backpack), it counts as any other object and is eligible for retrieving using the second bullet point of Mage Hand Legerdemain.

If you want this to go unnoticed, then you will indeed need to contest your Sleight of Hand skill check their Perception check, but you don't have to if you are okay with them noticing.

## No, if it is not stored in a container.

The requirements for the feature are very specific about the object being in a container. If the weapon were strapped to the opponent's back or leg, for example, you would not be able to use Mage Hand Legerdemain to steal it.

This makes sense thematically because something the opponent can reach for easily is far more attended than something the opponent would have to search for in a container.

For more details about what constitutes a container for these purposes, see the following related question with several different interpretations in the answers: [Can an Arcane Trickster use Mage Hand Legerdemain to steal the bolt out of a crossbow?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122280/can-an-arcane-trickster-use-mage-hand-legerdemain-to-steal-the-bolt-out-of-a-cro)